# remove cairo dock completely

Tags: 14.04, cairo-dock

I recently installed `cairo-dock-core` package from Ubuntu software center.

I played with it for a while and concluded to delete it completely.Then, I uninstalled it from Ubuntu software center itself.

To check that it was completely removed I typed in terminal, the name of the package `cairo` and checked that if anything related was left.

To my surprise, I found `cairo-dock-session`. I then tried removing it but didn't succeed.

Comment: @P.-H. Lin Well, those tells me about how to remove the package if installed. But, I've already removed the package and left with the 'cairo-dock-session'

Comment: It also tells you how to remove unneeded dependencies of the packages, that you removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the [source package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/cairo-dock) of `cairo-dock` you'll get the list of packages to remove.
To fully remove this application you need to type the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data libgldi-dev libgldi3
```

**Note**:
`cairo-dock-session` is provided by the `cairo-dock-data` package (see this [query](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=cairo-dock-session&mode=filename&suite=trusty&arch=any) on packages.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Would be nice if they had made this easier...like Windows. (:

Comment: ```sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove``` . This worked for me.